# Adding browse function to button -Python

Tags: python, button, gtk

I have a button in my code:

```
self.add_bt = Gtk.Button()
self.add_bt.set_label(_("Choose from computer"))


vbox.pack_start(self.add_bt, False, False, 0)
```

I want to include FileChooser function on clicking this button.

```
dlg = Gtk.FileChooserDialog()
dlg.show()
```

What I am trying to do is, on clicking the button labelled "Choose from computer" I want the browse window to open.
Then get the added file included in place of current image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
self.add_bt.connect("clicked", self.on_add_bt_clicked)

def on_add_bt_clicked(self, button):
    dlg = Gtk.FileChooserDialog()
    dlg.show()
```